# Riemann normal coordinates and the interpretation of the curvature scalar

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature, approximations

I have read two demonstrations regarding the interpretation of the Ricci scalar:

https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401099 (page 13)

And

https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1395 (Page 258)

Both expositions are essentially the same and excellent. I am struggling with one step they both share. Not long into the demonstration they assert the use of Riemann normal coordinates (“RNC”) and then they write that the the coordinates of a point a geodesic distance $\lambda$ Away is (using the notation of the second reference):

$$ x^\mu(\lambda) = x^\mu_0 + \lambda v^\mu + \frac{\lambda^3}{18}\partial_{(d} \Gamma^\mu_{bc)} V^d v^b v^c $$

This formula propagates through the entire demonstration and is quite critical to the proof. In particular the symmetric derivative ultimately combines with other terms to produce the Riemann tensor. I have no trouble understanding the origin of this formula. For example, I understand that in RNC $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\gamma} = 0$ at $x_0^\mu$ and therefore there is no quadratic term. The issue I am struggling with is that in RNC, I thought, *all symmetric derivatives of the connection are also zero* which would make the rightmost term zero. This can be quickly demonstrated by taking derivatives of the geodesic equation and taking a geodesic path to be a line at the origin (see, for example, http://users.monash.edu.au/~leo/research/papers/files/lcb96-01.pdf equation 3.3)

So my question is, “Why keep *any* terms past $\lambda v^\mu$ in the expression?” Also, related to that, why did both papers bother to symmetrize the derivative of the connection? What benefit was there to doing that?

Aside from this point I have no trouble following either paper. It is just the point of keeping that symmetric derivative. I don’t doubt that my problem is algebraic and that I am missing something simple. If that is the case, my apologies in advance! The proof/demonstrations are quite wonderful.

Comment: Just a quick guess without having considered it carefully, but it may be that these derivatives are zero only at a point, but not in any neighborhood of that point.

Comment: That is true, for sure. The term I am worried about is only zero at the origin, but I am quite sure that is exactly where the term is evaluated! In fact, the connection is only zero at the origin too, and the second order term is missing for that exact reason! So I'm still puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the symmetrization is automatic because the $v^dv^bv^c$ automatically symmetrizes $\partial_d {\Gamma^a}_{bc}$ (note that, compared to your second referece,  you have a typo $d\to a$ in your equation.)

I don't know about the rest. One  can extend  normal coordinates to an exponential map it which a geodestic from the origin was $x^\mu = v^\mu \lambda$ all the way until the exponential map becomes mutlivalued. In that case your puzzling term would indeed be zero.

There is however freedom to  change the higher order terms by making coordinate changes that are cubic in $x$. 
Suppose that we have constructed  coordinates at O such that 
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x)= \delta_{\mu\nu}+\frac 12 A_{\mu \nu\sigma \tau} x^\sigma x^\tau + O(|x|^3),
$$
where $A_{\mu\nu\sigma\tau}$  is symmetric under $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$ and under $\sigma\leftrightarrow \tau$. 
Then
$$
{\Gamma^{\lambda}}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac 12(A_{\lambda\mu\nu\tau}+A_{\lambda\nu\mu\tau}-A_{\mu\nu\lambda\tau})x^\tau+O(|x^2|),
$$
and
$$
R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}(0)= \frac 12(A_{\rho\nu\sigma\mu}-A_{\nu\sigma\mu\rho}+A_{\mu\sigma\nu\rho}-A_{\rho\mu\sigma\nu}).
$$
We can verify that this curvature tensor  satisfies the pair exchange symmetry $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}= R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$, the two antisymmetries 
$$
R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}=- R_{\sigma\rho\mu\nu}= -R_{\rho\sigma\nu\mu}
$$
and  the first Bianchi identity:
$$
R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}+R_{\rho\mu\nu\sigma}+R_{\rho\nu\sigma\mu}=0.
$$
Now in d=4, for example, the  array of numbers  $A_{\mu\nu\sigma\tau}$ has 10$\times$10=100 independent entries  while its  symmetries lead $R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$ to have  only 20. We have,  however, at our disposal  80
degrees of freedom in the  coefficients ${b^\mu}_{\rho\sigma\tau}$
$$
x^\mu \to x^\mu + {b^\mu}_{\rho\sigma\tau} x^\rho x^\sigma x^\tau+\ldots
$$
 of a  local change-of-coordinates expansion that keeps the metric euclidean up to quadratic corrections.
We should therefore be able to find a co-ordinate system in which $A_{\nu\sigma\mu\rho}$  is expressed in terms of $R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$.  Indeed, counting degrees of freedom shows that  in any number of dimensions   we can use a  cubic change of co-ordinate to  reduce $A_{\mu\nu\sigma\tau}$ to the form 
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x)= \delta_{\mu\nu}- \frac 13 R_{\mu\sigma \nu\tau}(0) x^\sigma x^\tau + O(|x|^3).
$$
and
$$
{\Gamma^{\lambda}}_{\mu\nu}(x)= -\frac 13 (R_{\lambda\nu\mu\tau}+R_{\lambda\mu\nu\tau})x^\tau+ O(|x|^2).
$$
Then, as you say, the $\partial_{(d} {\Gamma^a}_{bc)}$ are zero by the first Bianchi identity.  (symmetrization bracket added in later edit to correct mistake)

Comment: Thank you Mike. Let me work through this a bit. Note, regarding the last line of your answer, I did not mean to say the first derivatives of the connection are zero, just the *symmetric* first derivative. Also, I agree with your statement regarding $x = \lambda v^a$ being the *exact* expression for coordinates in RNC. At least, that is what I thought when I learned the subject. It was, I understood, exact *by definition*

Comment: Yes. I meant the symmetrized derivative in the last line :)

Comment: Thanks again for you answer. I do follow and appreciate it. I can’t declare it the “answer” because it does not tackle the question directly, but it was insightful. In some sense, you showed another way to be puzzled: the symmetric derivative under the type of coordinate change you described was still zero!

Comment: Thanks.  I I thank that the point is that there is more than one notion of "geodesic" or "normal" co-ords in the literature: one that makes just the $\Gamma$'s vanish at O. This def is not unique because we have the freedom of cubic and higher coordinate redefs. The second  is the exponential map in which radial geodesics are $x^\mu=v^\mu \lambda$ all the way. This  a particular case of the first.

Comment: I am still thinking about this. I need to check the proof makes any sense in the particular case when the symmetric term is zero. At first look, that would mean that in that “version” of RNC the curvature tensor is equal to a certain second derivative fo the metric, which I don’t think is correct. So I am still puzzled for now!

Comment: I think I got it. You must be right about different versions of normal coordinates. I think the paper just didn’t realize that what it was calling “Riemann normal coordinates” were only partially so as you say. To show this, I set the symmetrized term to 0 and completed the proof successfully under the assumption of true RNC. It is strange: the proof is clearer and easier my way. Thanks for you help. I will affirm your response as an answer.